# How to embed excel file on html

Tags: html, excel

I have an excel file which I want to embed into my html webpage. Meaning, I want to directly show the spreadsheet onto my webpage as plain text where others can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open that excel file and save it as html... i think you can use the code there...
If you also need to do some editing in your web page... it will be a little more difficult

Comment: did it. worked successfully. requires some effort for formatting and editing though. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

what about this:
by using  tag u can embed ur excel file into web page
also u can changes & add parameters like following code
example:

```
<object 
width = 900
height = 500
id = 'excel'
classid = 'CLSID:0002E510-0000-0000-C000-000000000046' VIEWASTEXT>
<param name=DisplayTitleBar value=true >
<param name="DataType" value="CSVURL">
<param name="AutoFit" value="0">
<param name="DisplayColHeaders" value="1">
<param name="DisplayGridlines" value="1">
<param name="DisplayHorizontalScrollBar" value="1">
<param name="DisplayRowHeaders" value="1">
<param name="DisplayTitleBar" value="1">
<param name="DisplayToolbar" value="1">
<param name="DisplayVerticalScrollBar" value="1">
<param name="EnableAutoCalculate" value="0">
<param name="EnableEvents" value="0">
<param name="MoveAfterReturn" value="1">
<param name="MoveAfterReturnDirection" value="0">
<param name="RightToLeft" value="0">
</object>
```

Comment: how do i specify the location of my excel sheet?

Comment: @AyushKhemka:check my new answer

Answer (score 1):

You can generate embedded iframe tag from excel file by going to...
File>Embed>Generate and
then pasted the generated iframe tag in your html web file.