# How to convert XLSX to JPG or display XLSX in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/logo.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles\default.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg">
        <img id="currentPhoto" src="original/original.jpeg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='error.jpeg'; this.class='center'" alt="" class="center">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, it just showes the picture in the center of a website. It works fine but my "techical director" told me: "Yes, I like this but I need you now to make it so I can put an XLSX file in the "original" folder anytime and see it on the website".
Now, I'm basically stuck here because I need to somehow "convert" it to "original.jpeg" or smth like that to make it possible. Maybe there is a way to display XLSX without formatting it to JPG.. Any ideas?
(I'm newbie so don't blame me please)

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551190/how-to-embed-excel-file-on-html

Comment: Yes, this was my first idea of how to make this whole thing work, but this idea crashed when my techical director told that he wants to just put a xlsx file in folder and it should work. I can't find any information with those terms..

Comment: I would try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62720506/2817442 no upvotes, but it might work.

Comment: Yep, it actually worked and works pretty nice, but now I need to actually somehow stylize it to look nice, clear and beatiful.  

Comment: You would need to post what you succeeded to do until now with that in a separate new question.